# Is IDisposable a behaviour as Liskof meant it?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

Should IDisposable be implemented on base classes, despite not being needed there, just to fullfill Liskov for optionally IDisposable subclasses?

Answer (score 3):

The `IDisposable` interface is a bit weird.  Most interfaces impose semantic requirements on the classes that implement them, but `IDisposable` does not.  Any class which wouldn't require `IDisposable` could legitimately implement it by defining a `Dispose` method that does nothing.  Thus, having `IDisposable` be an interface goes somewhat against normal usage.

Problems stemming from this, however, are generally confined to one particular scenario: a function which returns a new instance of a type that may require cleanup (e.g. `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` returns `IEnumerator<T>`, which implements `IDisposable`).  A factory that returns something requiring cleanup is not substitutable for a factory that returns something that can simply be abandoned.  The way to avoid substitutability problems is to have a base factory defined to return a type which "may" require cleanup, but will implement `IDisposable.Dispose` whether it actually does or not.  Callers that call `Dispose` on instances when they're no longer needed will work correctly with instances that use `Dispose` to perform required cleanup as well as with those whose `Dispose` method does nothing.